# How i can convert mongoose json result to array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a sample code that shows the result and want to convert the result into array.

```
TranModel
        .find({ quantityout: 1 }, 
                        { _id: 0} )
        .sort({ tag: 1 })
        .select( 'tag' )
        .populate( 'createdby' )
        .exec(function(err, data){
            if(err){
                res.json(err)
            } else {
                res.json(data)
            }
        })
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "tag": "TH000001"
  },
  {
    "tag": "TH000006"
  },
  {
    "tag": "TH000009"
  },
  {
    "tag": "TH000011"
  },
  {
    "tag": "TH000014"
  }
]
```

And I need convert result to like this

```
[
  "TH000001",
  "TH000006",
  "TH000009",
  "TH000011",
  "TH000014"
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get that directly from a Mongoose `find` query, but you manipulate the output using the JavaScript [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to get what you're looking for:

```
TranModel
    .find({ quantityout: 1 }, 
          { _id: 0} )
    .sort({ tag: 1 })
    .select( 'tag' )
    .exec(function(err, docs){
        docs = docs.map(function(doc) { return doc.tag; });
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            res.json(docs)
        }
    })
```

I took out the `populate` call because that doesn't make any sense here because you're not including `createdBy` in the output.

Comment: Thank you #JohnnyHK, Work fine for me.